# The procedure entry point terminate could not be located in dynamic link library

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I wrote a program in Python 3.6.2 **(32 bit)**, I converted it to an `.exe` file using `cx_freeze`.

When I run it in Windows 8 **(64 bit)**, it needs the below DLLs inside the project:

```
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
```

when I add `api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll` and run the project, I get the error:

```
The procedure entry point terminate could not be located in dynamic link library.
C:\users\seyed_vahid\Desktop\exe.win32-3.6\MegaGram.exe
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See [Pyinstaller onefile does not start on some Windows 7 machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218333/pyinstaller-onefile-does-not-start-on-some-windows-7-machines/34283691#34283691) .

The workaround seems to be to

- Install all Windows updates.
- Install the Microsoft Visual C runtime [redistributable package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows).